# How to restrict typenames in template

Tags: c++

Have a function which can accept 4 different types. And their implementations are very similar.

```
template< typename T >
void foo( std::string &&name, T value ){
    //...
}
```

`typename T` must be one of 4 predefined types. Other typenames is not acceptable, and should be restricted at compile-time.
Is it possible to write in C++?

Comment: Please show the expected behaviour using foo. Could not get you completely

Comment: Keep the template private and have four public non-template overloads that delegate to the template?

Comment: You will have to specialize the template

Comment: You could probably just do 4 overloads instead.

Comment: Instead of "artificially" restricting the template to certain types, consider just documenting their requirements if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<type_traits>` let you generalize your logic into class template. How this works is we take template parameter `T` and parameter pack of `Ts` and we start checking if `T` is same to `Head` of the list of types. If match is found, we inherit from `std::true_type` and we are done. If no match is found, we pop the head and recursively instantiate same template with tail of `Ts`. Eventually, if no match is found at all, parameter pack size will drop to zero and the compiler will instantiate base template class that inherit from `std::false_type`. Please check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY) for much better and in dept explanation by Mr. Walter E. Brown.

```
template<class T, class...> struct is_any_of: std::false_type{};
template<class T, class Head, class... Tail> 
struct is_any_of<T, Head, Tail...>: std::conditional_t<
  std::is_same<T, Head>::value, 
  std::true_type,
  is_any_of<T, Tail...>>
{};
```

Now we can SFINAE over, using [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in almost English wording.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<
  class T,
  class = std::enable_if_t<is_any_of<T, int, float, unsigned, double>::value>
>
void foo(std::string &&str, T value) {}


int main()
{
  foo(std::string{"hello"}, 3);
  foo(std::string{"world"}, '0'); //compile-time error
}
```

SFANIE is a language feature, a tool, that's used or *abused* some say to achieve what you ask for,

> The standard library component std::enable_if allows for creating a substitution failure in order to enable or disable particular overloads based on a condition evaluated at compile time.
>   FYI http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae.

Note that `std::conditional_t<>` and `std::enable_if_t<>` are shorthanded from `std::conditional<>::type` and `std::enable_if<>::type` respectively. You could simple replace these in code, but should put `typename` keyword before `enable_if` then.

Comment: could you, please, comment what is done in 1st line more detailed? What is SFINAE?

Comment: **CLion+mingw** can't understand `enable_if_t` and `conditional_t`. `<type_traits>` and `<typeinfo>` are included.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of at least three ways, off the top of my head.

First:

```
namespace internal {
template< typename T >
void foo_impl( std::string &&name, T value ) {
    // actual implementation here
}
}

void foo(std::string &&name, SpecialType1 value ) {
    internal::foo_impl(std::forward<std::string>(name), value);
}
void foo(std::string &&name, SpecialType2 value ) {
    internal::foo_impl(std::forward<std::string>(name), value);
}
```

Second:

```
template< typename T >
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, SpecialType1>::value ||
                        std::is_same<T, SpecialType2>::value >::type
foo( std::string &&name, T value ){
    //implementation here
}
```

Third:

```
template< typename T >
void foo(std::string &&name, T value){
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, SpecialType1>::value ||
                  std::is_same<T, SpecialType2>::value,
    "wrong template argument");
    //implementation here
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MXYVZ89644)

Comment: #1 is my favourite for sure. It makes the _interface_ documenting, which is not always easy when playing with black magic meta-template hackery.

Comment: Also #1 will work with types that are implicitly convertible to a `SpecialType`, while number 2 and 3 won't.

Comment: @sbabbi One could replace `is_same` with `is_convertible`, if desired.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes but then you (probably) need to actually perform the conversion, instead of working on `T` directly.

Comment: (@p0pa)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/35243426/3743145 ] has more extended solution relative to **#2**. 
**#1**'s std::forward looks as old good `int i; float f = *(float*)&i;`. Don't like.
Thank you for ideas.

Comment: Note that the use of `std::forward` is not central to the example - it's just there to deal with your rvalue reference parameter, and is in fact an idiomatic, standard-blessed way to forward such parameters. `std::forward` is invented for this very purpose. I don't at all see what it has in common with your example of type punning.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have seen people done is using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). I don't know exactly what your 4 types are, so this is an example with two types `int` and `float`.

```
using myType = std::enable_if<
std::is_same<int, T>::value ||
std::is_same<float, T>::value, T >::type;
```

`myType` exists only if `T` is exactly `int` or `float`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party but maybe someone will find this useful.

As of `C++20` one can use [constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) and [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) to filter possible `typename`s in a template.

The syntax goes like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
requires std::is_integral_v<T>
auto func(T any_integer) {
  ...
};

// Or, you can also do:

template <typename T>
concept Integer = std::is_integral_v<T>;

template <Integer T>
auto func(T any_integer) {
  ...
};

// Or, an even better approach:

auto func(Integer auto any_integer) {
  ...
};
```

I prefer the last one since it's nice and clean. But, that's just my opinion.

Following are some valid calls to `func()`:

```cpp
func(int{});         // OK!
func(long{});        // OK!
func(bool{});        // Yes, it's OK too!
func(char{});        // Yes, it's OK too!
```

Now, some invalid calls to `func()`:

```cpp
func(double{});      // Compiler error!
func(std::string{}); // Compiler error!
```

The compiler will also give a clean error message depending on your usage:

> note: candidate: ‘template  requires  is_integral_v void func(T)’

or

> note: candidate: ‘template  requires  Integer auto func(T)’

or

> note: candidate: ‘template  requires  Integerauto:15 auto func(auto:15)’

References:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral