# Conversion is ambiguous. Standard implicit conversion could not choose cast operator

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a custom type described as

```
struct A {
    double dbl_;
    bool boo_;
    operator double() const { return dbl_; }
    //operator bool() const { return boo_; }
};
```

And now I want to cast it to simple types. When `operator bool()` is undefined `a` can be implicitly converted to any simple type int, unsigned, float, etc. But with `operator bool()` conversion is ambiguous.

```
A a;
cout << (double) a << endl;
cout << (float) a << endl; //error: conversion from 'A' to 'float' is ambiguous; candidates are: A::operator bool() const; A::operator double() const
cout << (int) a << endl;  // the same
cout << (char) a << endl; // the same
return 0;
```

Runnable code on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/3scp)

**I know a few ways to fix that:**

1.add type conversion operators for **all** the expected types.

```
 operator int() const { return (int)dbl_; }
 // and so on...
```

This looks like bad practice.

2.use *[template with restricted types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242266/how-to-restrict-typenames-in-template)*.

```
template<class T, class...> struct is_any_of: std::false_type{};
template<class T, class Head, class... Tail>
struct is_any_of<T, Head, Tail...> : std::conditional<
        std::is_same<T, Head>::value,
        std::true_type,
        is_any_of<T, Tail...> >::type
{};

template<
        class T,
        class = typename std::enable_if<is_any_of<T, int, float, unsigned, double>::value>::type
>
operator T() const {
    if(type_ != Type::NUMBER) throw Node::Exception("not is number");
    return dbl_;
}
```

3.Hold `bool` value in `dbl_`, because only one of them is used. Not cool, as for me.

May be a more refined solution exists? Like

```
operator bool() const no_implicit_conversation_to_other_types_specifier { return boo_; }
```

The question is at most theory of C++.

**Upd.** no_implicit_conversation_to_other_types_specifier is `explicit`

```
explicit operator bool() const { return boo_; }
```

### [Run](http://cpp.sh/4l4iv).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making all your conversion operators *explicit* (to prevent implicit conversions) would be a good start:

```
struct A {
    double dbl_;
    bool boo_;
    explicit operator double() const { return dbl_; }
    explicit operator bool() const { return boo_; }
};
```

I'm not *sure*, but I imagine this would help to prevent the ambiguities too.

Comment: Cool. `no_implicit_conversation_to_other_types_specifier` is `explicit` )

Comment: So. To make what I want `explicit` should be added only before `operator bool()`. It works http://cpp.sh/4l4iv

Comment: @kyb: Glad to hear it. Implicit conversions are the devil's work, and this is why!

Comment: `and this is why!` why? May be sometimes they are very useful?

Comment: @kyb: It's possible. I can't think of any examples.

Comment: I can. `Integer integer = 25; int i = integer;` Like Java.

Comment: @kyb: That's an explicit conversion! It doesn't use an operator either. Even if you were to attempt `i = integer`, I think requiring a cast here is _far_ superior. C++ is not Java. It does not have unboxing/boxing concerns.